# How can I add these coffee prices?

Tags: python

Example: 2 orders. 1s order is $1 and the 2nd order is $2 so the total price is $3.

```
N = int(input())
for i in range(N):
    price = float(input())
    date = str(input())
    parse = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, "%d/%m/%Y")
    date1 = calendar.monthrange(parse.year, parse.month)[1]
    capsule = int(input())
    cofeeprice = (date1*capsule)*price
    print(cofeeprice)
```

Comment: Using addition?  `price1 + price2`.  If you're asking how to sum across iterations of your loop, you'll have to have some variable initialized to `0` outside your loop that you add the prices to.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want to sum all values on your loop, you must do as @Patrick Haugh said on the comments and have a variable outside the loop. This variable will be increased with each loop passage and in the end it will have the sum of all order's prices.

```
N = int(input())
sum = 0
for i in range(N):
    price = float(input())
    date = str(input())
    parse = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, "%d/%m/%Y")
    date1 = calendar.monthrange(parse.year, parse.month)[1]
    capsule = int(input())
    cofeeprice = (date1*capsule)*price
    sum = sum + cofeeprice
    print(cofeeprice)
    print(sum) # the price of all orders so far added together

print(sum) # the price of all orders added together
```